# Generic transform/fold/map over tuple/hlist containing some F[_]

Tags: scala, scalaz, shapeless, scalaz7, type-level-computation

I recently asked [Map and reduce/fold over HList of scalaz.Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26410100/) and got a great answer as to how to transform a fixed sized tuple of `Va[T]` (which is an alias for `scalaz.Validation[String, T]`) into a `scalaz.ValidationNel[String, T]`.  I've since then been studying Shapeless and type level programming in general to try to come up with a solution that works on tuples of any size.

This is what I'm starting out with:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._, shapeless._, contrib.scalaz._, syntax.std.tuple._

type Va[A] = Validation[String, A]

// only works on pairs of Va[_]
def validate[Ret, In1, In2](params: (Va[In1], Va[In2]))(fn: (In1, In2) => Ret) = {
  object toValidationNel extends Poly1 {
    implicit def apply[T] = at[Va[T]](_.toValidationNel)
  }
  traverse(params.productElements)(toValidationNel).map(_.tupled).map(fn.tupled)
}
```

so then `validate` is a helper I call like this:

```
val params = (
  postal  |> nonEmpty[String]("no postal"),
  country |> nonEmpty[String]("no country") >=> isIso2Country("invalid country")
)

validate(params) { (postal, country) => ... }
```

I started out by taking any `Product` instead of a pair and constraining its contents to `Va[T]`:

```
// needs to work with a tuple of Va[_] of arbitrary size
def validateGen[P <: Product, F, L <: HList, R](params: P)(block: F)(
  implicit
  gen: Generic.Aux[P, L],
  va:  UnaryTCConstraint[L, Va],
  fp:  FnToProduct.Aux[F, L => R]
) = ???
```

I do have the feeling that simply adding the constraint only makes sure the input is valid but doesn't help at all with implementing the body of the function but I don't know how to go about correcting that.

`traverse` then started complaining about a missing evidence so I ended up with:

```
def validateGen[P <: Product, F, L <: HList, R](params: P)(block: F)(
  implicit
  gen: Generic.Aux[P, L],
  va:  UnaryTCConstraint[L, Va],
  tr:  Traverser[L, toValidationNel.type],
  fp:  FnToProduct.Aux[F, L => R]
) = {
  traverse(gen.to(params): HList)(toValidationNel).map(_.tupled).map(block.toProduct)
}
```

The compiler however continued to complain about a missing `Traverser[HList, toValidationNel.type]` implicit parameter even though it's there.

Which additional evidence do I need to provide to the compiler in order for the `traverse` call to compile? Has it got to do with the `UnaryTCConstraint` not being declared in a way that is useful to the `traverse` call, i.e. it cannot apply `toValidationNel` to `params` because it cannot prove that `params` contains only `Va[_]`?

*P.S.* I also found [leftReduce Shapeless HList of generic types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23163353/leftreduce-shapeless-hlist-of-generic-types) and tried to use `foldRight` instead of `traverse` to no avail; the error messages weren't too helpful when trying to diagnose which evidence the compiler was really lacking.

**UPDATE:**

As per what lmm has pointed out, I've removed the cast to `HList`, however, the problem's now that, whereas in the non-generic solution I can call `.map(_.tupled).map(block.toProduct)` on the result of the `traverse` call, I'm now getting:

> value map is not a member of shapeless.contrib.scalaz.Out

How come it's possible that it was possible on the result of the `traverse(params.productElements)(toValidationNel)` call and not the generic traverse?

**UPDATE 2:**

Changing the `Traverser[...]` bit to `Traverser.Aux[..., Va[L]]` helped the compiler figure out the expected result type of the traversal, however, this only makes the `validateGen` function compile successfully but yields another error at the call site:

```
[error] could not find implicit value for parameter tr: shapeless.contrib.scalaz.Traverser.Aux[L,toValidationNel.type,Va[L]]
[error]     validateGen(params) { (x: String :: String :: HNil) => 3 }
[error]                         ^
```

I'm also getting the feeling here that the `UnaryTCConstraint` is completely unnecessary — but I'm still too new to Shapeless to know if that's the case.

**UPDATE 3:**

Having realized the type that comes out of the traverser cannot be `Va[L]` because `L` itself is already a hlist of `Va[_]`, I've split the `L` type parameter to `In` and `Out`:

```
def validateGen[P <: Product, F, In <: HList, Out <: HList, R](params: P)(block: F)(
  implicit
  gen: Generic.Aux[P, In],
  va:  UnaryTCConstraint[In, Va],  // just for clarity
  tr:  Traverser.Aux[In, toValidationNel.type, Va[Out]],
  fn:  FnToProduct.Aux[F, Out => R]
): Va[R] = {
  traverse(gen.to(params))(toValidationNel).map(block.toProduct)
}
```

this compiles well — I'd be curious to find out how come the previous version with `Va[L]` being the return value (i.e. the 3rd param to `Traverser.Aux`) even compiled — however, at the call site, I now get:

> Unspecified value parameters tr, fn

Answer (score 2):

You have a `Traverser[L, toValidationNel.type]` which is not the same thing as `Traverser[HList, toValidationNel.type]` (which would have to work for any `HList` - no chance). I don't know why you've written `gen.to(params): HList`, but this is throwing away type information; shouldn't that be of type `L`?

This will probably only kick the problem one level higher; I doubt you'll be able to get the `Traverser` you need automatically. But you should be able to write an implicit method that supplies one based on the `UnaryTCConstraint`, and it's possible shapeless already includes that and it will Just Work.

Update:

In the first example, the compiler knew the specific `Traverser` instance it was using, so it knew what the `Out` type was. In `validateGen` you haven't constrained anything about `tr.Out`, so the compiler has no way of knowing that it's a type that supports `.map`. If you know what the output of the traverse needs to be then you can probably require an appropriate `Traverser.Aux` i.e.:

```
tr: Traverser.Aux[L, toValidationNel.type, Va[L]]
```

(Just don't ask me how to make sure the type inference still works).

I think you probably *don't* want the `.map(_.tupled)`, because the `_` there is already a `HList` (I suspect it's redundant in the original `validate` too), but I've never used `.toProduct` before so maybe you have it right.

Update 2:

Right, this is as I initially suspected. Looking at the implementation of `Sequencer` I suspect you're right and the `UnaryTCConstraint` will be subsumed by the `Traverser`. If you're not using it then no point requiring it.

The only advice I can give is to chase through the calls that should be providing your implicits. E.g. the `Traverser` should be coming from `Traverser.mkTraverser`. So if you try calling `Traverser.mkTraverser[String :: String :: HNil, toValidationNel.type, Va[String] :: Va[String] :: HNil]` then you should be able to see whether it's the Mapper or the Sequencer that can't be found. Then you can recurse through the implicit calls that should happen until you find a simpler case of something that should be working, but isn't.

Comment: Really dumb of me to have kept that cast to `HList` — removed that and the traverse started working nicely, however, now the `.map()` call on the return value fails to compile; I've updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! I actually figured out the `Traverser.Aux` on my own by looking and The Source; as to `.tupled` in the original `validate`, it turns a `HList` to tuple so that it can be passed to `block.tupled`. In any case, the function itself compiles now but no instance of `Traverser.Aux` can be found at the call site...

Answer (score 0):

After long hours of experimentation, frustration and dead brain cells, I've started from scratch without `Traverser` and instead gone with `Mapper` and `Sequencer`; I'll later try to see if I can make it use `Traverser` again (if not for practicality, at least for learning purposes):

```
def validate[P <: Product, F, L1 <: HList, L2 <: HList, L3 <: HList, R](params: P)(block: F)(
  implicit
  gen: Generic.Aux[P, L1],
  mp:  Mapper.Aux[toValidationNel.type, L1, L2],
  seq: Sequencer.Aux[L2, VaNel[L3]],
  fn:  FnToProduct.Aux[F, L3 => R]
): VaNel[R] = {
  sequence(gen.to(params).map(toValidationNel)).map(block.toProduct)
}
```

Here's proof — pun intended — that it runs http://www.scastie.org/7086.

Comment: If you have a `Mapper.Aux[toValidationNel.type, L1, L2]` and a `Sequencer.Aux[L2, VaNel[L3]]` then you should be able to get a `Traverser.Aux[L1, toValidationNel.type, VaNel[L3]]`. I'm surprised that `VaNel[L3]` is inferrable though - you might need to make that another type and have an implicit witness that it's the same as the type in the `FnToProduct.Aux`.