# Map Shapeless hlist type F[T1] :: ... :: F[Tn] :: HNil to the type T1 :: ... :: Tn :: HNil (type level sequencing)

Tags: scala, shapeless, type-level-computation

I'm building a generic function that takes in a `HList` of the form `F[T1] ::  ... :: F[Tn] :: HNil`, converts that into a `F[T1 :: ... :: Tn :: HNil]` and then needs to pass that into a block that was passed in. However, in order for that to work, I need to extract the HList type in that `F[_]`.  I've found something remotely relevant under Shapeless' [`hlistconstraints`](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/hlistconstraints.scala):

```
/**
 * Type class witnessing that every element of `L` has `TC` as its outer type constructor. 
 */
trait UnaryTCConstraint[L <: HList, TC[_]]
```

...but this can only be used to verify that the hlist passed in is indeed made up of just `F[_]`; there seems to be no way however to extract that `_` bit so to say to a hlist of its own.

Where should I be looking to find something to do the job? Or should I just not expect to find anything out of the box and instead build the type computation myself?

*Disclosure: this question is an auxilliary to [Generic transform/fold/map over tuple/hlist containing some F[_]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26487430/generic-transform-fold-map-over-tuple-hlist-containing-some-f) but is nevertheless at least as useful as a standalone question, in my opinion.*

Comment: Can you give an example of input and expected output for a simple case?

Comment: Is this even possible? Wouldn't `List[Int] :: List[String] :: HList` only ever be able to become a `List[Int :: String :: HList]` iff each list was of the exact same length or are you looking to make a cross product?

Comment: @Nate: good point; let's just say it needs to work with stuff like Validation and Option wherein only at most one element is contained.

Comment: It'd work as a product... So for example if you have `List("a")::List(1,2)::HNil` the result of such operation would be `List("a"::1::HNil,"a"::2::HNil)`

Answer (score 3):

Looks like [Sequencer](https://github.com/typelevel/shapeless-contrib/blob/master/scalaz/main/scala/sequence.scala) already does this:

```
import scala.language.higherKinds

class Wrap[TC[_]] {
  def foo[L1 <: HList, L2 <: HList](xs: L1)(implicit
    seq: Sequencer.Aux[L1, TC[L2]] // L2 is the type we're looking for
  ): L2 = ???
}

val ret = new Wrap[Option].foo(1.some :: 2.some :: HNil)
// ret now has type Int :: Int :: HNil
```

...but I'm currently unable to think of a way to make this nicer by

- getting rid of the wrapper class;
- having Scala infer `TC` to be `Option`.

*Note: I think this is somewhat useful as an answer but I'm not accepting it — hoping someone will come up with a more generic and nicer looking solution.*

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve that is necessary that `F` has at least applicative capabilities. Once you ensure that, it's quite possible as in this code:

```
trait HApplicative[Eff[_], InL <: HList] extends {
  type OutL <: HList
  def product: InL => Eff[OutL]
}

object HApplicative {
  case class HAppAux[Eff[_], InL <: HList, OutL0 <: HList](zipper: InL => Eff[OutL0]) extends HApplicative[Eff, InL] {
    type OutL = OutL0

    override def product: InL => Eff[OutL0] = zipper
  }

  implicit def nilHApp[Eff[_]](implicit app: Applicative[Eff]): HApplicative[Eff, HNil] {type OutL = HNil} =
    HAppAux[Eff, HNil, HNil](_ => app.pure(HNil))


  implicit def consHApp[Eff[_], InH, InT <: HList](
    implicit tailHApp: HApplicative[Eff, InT],
    app: Applicative[Eff]
  ): HApplicative[Eff, Eff[InH] :: InT] {type OutL = InH :: tailHApp.OutL} = HAppAux[Eff, Eff[InH] :: InT, InH :: tailHApp.OutL] {
    case (inH: Eff[InH]) :: inT => app.map2(inH, tailHApp.product(inT)) {
      case (head, tail) => head :: tail
    }
  }

  def product[Eff[_],InL<:HList](inL:InL)(implicit happ:HApplicative[Eff,InL]):happ.OutL = happ.product(inL)
}
```